# How to use 'after_initialize' in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

**UPDATE**

I wrongly checked the edgerails guide instead of the currently correct Rails 3 guide (which has no mention of after_initialize). Not sure why the edgerails guide is "incorrect" though - I thought edgerails guide was supposed to be the latest up-to-date guide?

I'm leaving this question as-is just in case someone comes looking for the same "problem".

Macro-style call to `after_initialize` is the way to go.

---

---

Should `after_initialize` be used as method or macro-style call ?

This works, but gives a deprecation warning:

```
def after_initialize
  logger.info "Called after_initialize"
end
```

DEPRECATION WARNING: Base#after_initialize has been deprecated, 
                         please use Base.after_initialize :method instead.

This works, and there is no warning:

```
after_initialize :do_this_after_initialize
def do_this_after_initialize
  logger.info "Called after_initialize"
end
```

But the *Active Record Validations and Callbacks Guide* in [10.4 after_initialize and after_find](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#after_initialize-and-after_find) says:

> ...If you try to register
>   after_initialize or after_find using
>   macro-style class methods, they will
>   just be ignored.  This behaviour is
>   due to performance reasons, since
>   after_initialize and after_find will
>   both be called for each record  found
>   in the database, significantly slowing
>   down the queries...

So that means that the macro-style usage is inefficient versus the method-style way?

(I *guess* the guide is wrong, 'cos code is king :D)

---

Another Update

---

A [commit here](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/38d31b0ef0b9c9616918819b5ac5b9d21c539fd7) from January 28, 2011, suggests that the correct way is still to use the macro-style call, not a `def after_initialize`.

Comment: I'm using after_initialize for example for builings associations. An example after_initialize :build_text, :unless => :text. Very helpful when using accepts_nested_attributes_for

Comment: Here is an updated link [for the Rails 4 guide on after_initialize](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#after-initialize-and-after-find)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The call backs should be used as macro style in your model: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html